# TemplateUrl directive: AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

it is possible to read the scope into templateUrl of directive?

I want to do something like this :

```
mDirective.directive('directive', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            types :'=types'
        },

templateUrl:'.mytemplate/'+scope.types+'.html'
```

Answer (score 7):

Scope is not available in the directive's templateUrl.  There is a feature request on github for this: [Either add scope to attributes that are passed to templateUrl function or preprocess attributes based on scope parameters](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2895).

Here are two options (the second being the more general purpose):

**Attribute:** Scope isn't available.  But the raw attributes are.  So, if the raw attribute works for you, for instance if it's just a static string like this:

```
<div directive types="test1"></div>
```

Then we can pass a function into `templateUrl`.  The second parameter will be the attributes, so you can construct a template URL with that string like this:

```
templateUrl: function(elem, attrs){ return ('mytemplate/'+attrs.types+'.html')},
```

But this doesn't work if `types` may change, so a better solution for you is likely:

**ngInclude** You can reference a scope variable inside an `ngInclude`source expression.   So instead of using `templateURL` we use `template` and then let `ngInclude` handle the setting/changing the template:

```
template: '<div ng-include src="\'mytemplate/\'+types+\'.html\'"></div>',
```

You could also manually compile and add your template inside the directive.  But using `ngInclude` is easy and also enables animation.

[demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AxZFXWURER2jzGVx289y?p=preview) showing both options, and with a couple buttons to toggle the template and see `ngInclude` switch.